# Centos inside Virtualbox -- how to set custom resolution?

Tags: centos, gnome, virtualbox, xrandr

I have Centos inside Virtualbox. I need custom resolution for my screen. I run xrandr as proposed on the net. New resolution appears in the dropdown. But it doesn't work. Virtualbox addons are installed. Virtualbox gives 60Mbs of memory. Here is what I do and what I get:

[image]

Popup error message in Russian says: Unable to apply selected configuration, didn't manage to apply CRT 241 controller configuration.

Comment: Have you installed Guest Additions? Also, what is amount of Video RAM is configured in VM settings?

Comment: @myaut, i've updated the question to give more details.

Comment: maybe the auto resize feature is enabled, check under the `View` menu, or press `Host + G` on the keyboard, and try setting the desired resolution again.

Comment: no, autoresize is disabled

Comment: As Dalvenjia sugested, enable autoresize. You can enable all the virtualbox services with the command: `$ VBoxClient --clipboard --draganddrop --seamless --display --checkhostversion` or use `$ VBoxClient-all`. 

Alternatively, you can just tick what you require from the **View** menu of the running virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

After adding the mode to the display, you can use `xrandr` to enable the mode on the display.  This can be done with the following command:

```
xrandr --output default --mode "1600x900_60.00"
```

Consult the output of `xrandr` without any options to verify the name of the display output you are targeting is indeed *default*.  If setting the mode fails, you may try creating & setting a mode with different parameters (resolution, refresh rate, etc).

Comment: Tried, this doesn't help.

Comment: This unfortunately does not work for me, either. Output: `xrandr: cannot find mode 1600x900_60.00`